# How to get out from HDMI?

Tags: javascript, smart-tv

I'm working on a programming project for smart TV LG, I just have connected to HDMI with the method `hcap.mode.setHcapMode` when I change mode 1 to mode 0, that's why I tried to change it at the PORTAL key code which is allowed by this mode (mode 0).

```js
//manipuler keydown event (LG remote control)
function manageLauncherKeyDown(keyCode) {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case hcap.key.Code.ENTER:
            connectHDMI();      
            break;       
        case hcap.key.Code.PORTAL:
            exit();
            break;
        case hcap.key.Code.GUIDE:
            exit();
            break;
        case hcap.key.Code.INFO:
            exit();
            break;      
    }
}
```

Connect to HDMI and put my application invisible:

```
 //connect to HDMI and puts the application invisible
 function connectHDMI(){
    var keyInput = parseInt(focusedElementKeyboard.split("btn")[1]);
    if (keyInput == 2) {

        // change to mode 0 to put my appliction invisible
        hcap.mode.setHcapMode({
            "mode" : hcap.mode.HCAP_MODE_0,
            "onSuccess" : function() {

                //connect to HDMI1
                hcap.externalinput.setCurrentExternalInput({
                    "type" : hcap.externalinput.ExternalInputType.HDMI,
                    "index" : 0 , 
                    "onSuccess" : function() {

                    }, 
                    "onFailure" : function(f) {
                    }
                });
            }, 
            "onFailure" : function(f) {
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

The code to exit from mode 0 to mode 1 to return to the application:

```
//to exit from mode 0 to mode 1
 function exit(){

    hcap.mode.setHcapMode({
        "mode" : hcap.mode.HCAP_MODE_1,
        "onSuccess" : function() {
            alert("onSuccess HCAP Mode 1");                     
        }, 
        "onFailure" : function(f) {
            alert("onFailure : errorMessage = " + f.errorMessage);
        }
    });

}
```

I just managed to launch to my application from HDMI(ChromeCast), 
I change the mode:I put it on mode 1, but HDMI stay connected in the background.

====>the application and HDMI was connected at the same time.

so i want to know how to disconnect from HDMI when i go back to my application?